# Is there any alternative way to call a react hook conditionally?

Tags: reactjs, function, if-statement, react-hooks, conditional-rendering

Using react hooks inside any function of condition is invalid. Neither can I do conditional rendering for a hook. Is there any way to use a hook with emplement condition? Please share code

Answer (score 0):

The only way

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!!myparam) {
    console.log("myparam", myparam)
  }
}, [myparam])
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide us any code snippet which your are trying to do?

If you are using useEffect hook then for conditional rendering you can do following code.

UseEffect(()=> { if(true) { Do some logic.}}, []);

UseEffect(()=> { Do some logic. }, [Add your state here])